# Prove that $\frac{\langle f^2,g\rangle_{L^2}}{\left\|f\right\|_{L^2}^2}\ge-\left\|g\right\|_{L^\infty}$ for $f\in L^2$ and $g\in L^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ be bounded, $f\in L^2(\Omega)$ and $g\in L^\infty(\Omega)$. How can we show, that $$\frac{\langle f^2,g\rangle_{L^2(\Omega)}}{\left\|f\right\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2}\ge-\left\|g\right\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}\tag{1}$$ is true? I tried to use the *Cauchy-Schwarz* and *Hölder inequality* but I wasn't able to obtain $(1)$.

Comment: $\int f^{2}\left(  g+\left\Vert g\right\Vert _{\infty}\right)  \geq0$